# Is there an MSSQL service or app that can act as a router of traffic?

Tags: sql-server, proxy, amazon-rds

I am aiming to setup a router/jump/forwarder/gatekeeper where the service sits on internal network and is whitelisted to connect to AWS RDS.

So instead of internal apps connecting directly to AWS RDS, they can connect via this jump server.

Comment: This wouldn't really be a function that SQL Server would serve .... your best bet would be a web-server of some sort that would take requests from your internal network clients, forward them on, and then return the response.  However, if the external IP address for your network is a static one, then that IP address could be whitelisted, and as long as your apps are only making calls from within the internal network, they'll be able to connect.  It sounds like maybe you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist ....?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what i am trying to control is the traffic going into that external IP. I need a forwarder so that external IP can only be accessed by this forwarder, and this forwarder can have a different type of authentication in place. The hard requirement is to have a whitelist on the external component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx worked perfectly for me. Just a simple service that forwards request on a specified port.